# Filling a Scala immutable Map from a database table

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a SQL database table with the following structure:

```
create table category_value (
  category varchar(25),
  property varchar(25)
);
```

I want to read this into a Scala `Map[String, Set[String]]` where each entry in the map is a set of all of the property values that are in the same category.
I would like to do it in a "functional" style with no mutable data (other than the database result set).

Following on the Clojure `loop` construct, here is what I have come up with:

```
def fillMap(statement: java.sql.Statement): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select category, property from category_value")

    @tailrec
    def loop(m: Map[String, Set[String]]): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
      if (resultSet.next) {
        val category = resultSet.getString("category")
        val property = resultSet.getString("property")
        loop(m + (category -> m.getOrElse(category, Set.empty)))
      } else m
    }

    loop(Map.empty)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, without using mutable data structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you like, you could try something around

```
def fillMap(statement: java.sql.Statement): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
  val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select category, property from category_value")
  Iterator.continually((resultSet, resultSet.next)).takeWhile(_._2).map(_._1).map{ res =>
    val category = res.getString("category")
    val property = res.getString("property")
    (category, property)
  }.toIterable.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)
}
```

Untested, because I don’t have a proper `sql.Statement`. And the `groupBy` part might need some more love to look nice.

**Edit**: Added the requested changes.

Comment: Before the `groupBy`, you need to put a `toIterable`, because `Iterators` don't have a `groupBy` function (they only implement things that can be returned as a derived iterator). 
Also, you can use `mapValues` after the `groupBy` to simplify things a little.

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to this problem.

#### Getting the data out of the database and into a list of rows.

I would use a Spring `SimpleJdbcOperations` for the database access, so that things at least appear functional, even though the ResultSet is being changed behind the scenes.

First, some a simple conversion to let us use a closure to map each row:

```
implicit def rowMapper[T<:AnyRef](func: (ResultSet)=>T) = 
  new ParameterizedRowMapper[T]{
    override def mapRow(rs:ResultSet, row:Int):T = func(rs)
  }
```

Then let's define a data structure to store the results. (You could use a tuple, but defining my own case class has advantage of being just a little bit clearer regarding the names of things.)

```
case class CategoryValue(category:String, property:String)
```

Now select from the database

```
val db:SimpleJdbcOperations = //get this somehow
val resultList:java.util.List[CategoryValue] = 
  db.query("select category, property from category_value",
    { rs:ResultSet => CategoryValue(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)) } )
```

#### Converting the data from a list of rows into the format that you actually want

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val result:Map[String,Set[String]] =
  resultList.groupBy(_.category).mapValues(_.map(_.property).toSet)
```

(You can omit the type annotations. I've included them to make it clear what's going on.)

Answer (score 1):

[Builders](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Builder.html) are built for this purpose. Get one via the desired collection type companion, e.g. `HashMap.newBuilder[String, Set[String]]`.

Comment: Aren't Builders implicitly mutable? I am driving more at a functional algorithm than a specific implementation. The question I ask myself is "Can I do this in a purely functional language like Haskell (if I knew Haskell :-))?"

Comment: Builders are mutable, of course. However, their `.result` is not (if it is a builder for an immutable type, of course). In a pure functional language, you will have to create copies; that is, start with an empty map and use adding methods, that yield new values all the time. A clever compiler/VM might optimise things.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is basically the same as my other solution, but it doesn't use Spring, and the logic for converting a `ResultSet`  to some sort of list is simpler than  Debilski's solution.

```
def streamFromResultSet[T](rs:ResultSet)(func: ResultSet => T):Stream[T] = {
   if (rs.next())
      func(rs) #:: streamFromResultSet(rs)(func)
   else
      rs.close()
      Stream.empty
}

def fillMap(statement:java.sql.Statement):Map[String,Set[String]] = {
   case class CategoryValue(category:String, property:String)

   val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("""
        select category, property from category_value
   """)

   val queryResult = streamFromResultSet(resultSet){rs =>
      CategoryValue(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2))
   }

   queryResult.groupBy(_.category).mapValues(_.map(_.property).toSet)
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to this is a utility that I wrote recently. I am experimenting with different techniques to achieve the same result in a functional manner to improve my grokking of functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one approach I can think of that does not include either mutable state or extensive copying*. It is actually a very basic technique I learnt in my first term studying CS. Here goes, abstracting from the database stuff:

```
def empty[K,V](k : K) : Option[V] = None

def add[K,V](m : K => Option[V])(k : K, v : V) : K => Option[V] = q => {
  if ( k == q ) {
    Some(v)
  }
  else {
    m(q)
  }
}

def build[K,V](input : TraversableOnce[(K,V)]) : K => Option[V] = {
  input.foldLeft(empty[K,V]_)((m,i) => add(m)(i._1, i._2))
}
```

Usage example:

```
val map = build(List(("a",1),("b",2)))

println("a " + map("a"))
println("b " + map("b"))
println("c " + map("c"))

> a Some(1)
> b Some(2)
> c None
```

Of course, the resulting function does not have type `Map` (nor any of its benefits) and has linear lookup costs. I guess you could implement something in a similar way that mimicks simple search trees.

(*) I am talking concepts here. In reality, things like value sharing might enable e.g. mutable list constructions without memory overhead.