# How to convert an anorm resultlist from a two-field data table to a Tuple2, in Scala

Tags: database, tuples, implicit-conversion, scala-collections, anorm

I have the following table (maximum number of records 999) I use for a lookup:

```
CREATE TABLE lga
(
  lgacode character varying(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000'::character varying,
  lganame character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_lga PRIMARY KEY (lganame),
  CONSTRAINT uk_lga UNIQUE (lgacode)
);
```

Using Anorm, I easily get a result list `lgas` of the type `List[models.LgaTable]`
How do I get this result list into the form `List[Tuple2[String,String]]`?

I searched Stack Overflow and found something close ([a link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927260/filling-a-scala-immutable-map-from-a-database-table) but this contained `Set`, which I have an aversion for, meanwhile: I just needed something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just call a map on your result:

```
val lgas: List[models.LgaTable] = ...
val lgas_tupled = lags.map(row => (row.lgacode, lganame))
```